# Removing root node of tree view for site map

Tags: asp.net, treeview, sitemap, nodes

i have a menu which sits on an asp.net page. i used a treeview control to display my sitemenu. only problem is i have a root node which practically does nothing.

currently my menu structure is as follows:

-empty root node
 I---Home
 I---Calendar
 I---....

but i would like it like this:
-Home
-Calendar
-....

so basically the root node should be removed or hidden, as long as the user cant click and or see it...

is there a simple way of doing this? i tried removing the empty < siteMapNode > tag but this gives me an error...

Comment: Your title says "Event Handling in ASP.NET WebForms".  What does your question have to do with event handling?

Comment: lol sorry that was the title of my previous question which i already solved...

Comment: why vote down? this happened by mistake and wasnt intended as the question's title....

Comment: How are you building the TreeView? Using a SiteMapDataSource?

Comment: yes...i have a root tag and a few underlying tags...i didnt find any attribute that lets me hide the root tag...

Comment: Shouldn't the root node be "Home"?

Comment: actually i did this based on a tutorial that had the root node as home :) but i dont want a tree-view-ish appearance, more like a list...but i dont know how to do it or what control would be more suitable

Comment: If you want a list... then why a treeview :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are properties in the SiteMapDataSource that help control this. Something like:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="_siteMapData" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" StartFromCurrentNode="true" />
<asp:TreeView ID="_tree" NodeWrap="true" ExpandDepth="1" DataSourceID="_siteMapData" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
```

Changing the value of `ShowStartingNode` should be what you need.

You can also change that value from the code-behind. This will change the initial node based on whether or not the current node has children or not (no children, go up a level):

```
SiteMapNode currNode = System.Web.SiteMap.CurrentNode;
_siteMapData.StartingNodeOffset = currNode != null && currNode.HasChildNodes ? 0 : -1;
```

Comment: thanks, this did the trick! the node is still there in-code but it isnt displayed anymore in the browser, exactly what i wanted!